# Can an Angular service directly change properties on component where it is injected (without a store/RxJs)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { DragAndDropService } from '../api/services/drag-and-drop.service';

export class DashboardComponent {
  myProperty = "hello"

  constructor(private dragAndDropService: DragAndDropService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dragAndDropService.alterMyProperty()
  }
}
```

**DragAndDropService.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DragAndDropService {

  alterMyProperty() {
    this.myProperty = "New String we are trying to alter";
  }
}
```

So of course this will not work due to scope. The service will look for "this.myProperty" within it's own class. But is there a way to have it default to the scope where it is instantiated (in this case, the constructor of Dashboard.component)??

This example is very simplified, I left code out for conciseness. My actual code is much more complex than this.

Comment: you can use RxJs subject to send the new value from service to the component

Comment: You probably need a store between your component and your service.

Comment: Technically you could have public properties on the service that `DashboardComponent` uses and provide an instance `DragAndDropService` to each instance of `DashboardComponent` rather than to root or even to the `NgModule` that `DashboardComponent` is part of. You may need to clarify at least conceptually why you'd need the service to alter properties on component. Each combination of the component + service could be "unique" and independent, allowing to modify properties without affecting other instances. Can it not instead take values and return the necessary modified values?

Comment: You could have something like this in the component code: `this.myProperty = this.dragAndDropService.getPropertyValue()`.

Comment: You could modify `alterMyProperty` so that it takes the component as an parameter. Then you can call it using `this.dragAndDropService.alterMyProperty(this)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use Rxjs. But it would make your life easy.

You can set the Component's property from the service itself.

Try this:

Dashboard.component.ts

```
import { DragAndDropService } from '../api/services/drag-and-drop.service';

export class DashboardComponent {
  myProperty = "hello"

  constructor(private dragAndDropService: DragAndDropService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dragAndDropService.alteredProperty$
      .subscribe(alertedProperty => this.myProperty = alertedProperty);
  }
}
```

DragAndDropService.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DragAndDropService {

  private alteredProperty: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  alteredProperty$: Observable<string> = this.alteredProperty.asObservable();

  alterMyProperty(alteredProperty) {
    this.alteredProperty.next(alteredProperty);
  }
}
```

You can now inject the `DragAndDropService` anywhere to call it's `alterMyProperty` method and pass it the value of the `alteredProperty`. As soon as this method is called, it will notify the DashboardComponent as it is `subscribe`ing to the `alteredProperty$` Observable.